# Software to PHP

Tags: software-development, php

I am developing software on PHP using a framework from Laravel, but I don't have start from the begin of the project.

What I want, if it exists, is some kind of software that for example when I am editing the variable `$x` know that this exists on `home.php`, `config.php`, and `layer.php`.

I want the software to try to identify the global variables where they are! For I don't be looking on the error and try to find out.

I have tried PHPStorm but it doesn't give me what I want, or I don't know very well to use it.

Any help?

Comment: Sounds like refactoring. Does your IDE have a Refactor menu?

Answer (score 1):

Any decent IDE should be able to do this for you.  While I am forced to use a customized Eclipse at work, I find Netbeans "easier" and "better" for my particular work style/pattern.  Both have PHP development options.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using *PHPStorm*, you can:

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> / [Find Usages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/find-usages-variable-options.html),
- or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> / [Finding and replacing text in a project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html),
- or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice... / [Search for a target by name](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/searching-everywhere.html).

I hope I helped :)

Comment: I would suggest looking for a "`Refactor/Rename`" menu item

Comment: i am using netbeans